# Keras model.predict with sigmoid activation and binary cross entropy returns only 0 or 1, not probability

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I am building NN in Keras with overlapping class predictions. From what I understand, the 'sigmoid' activation function should return probability of belonging to a class. However, when I try to use model.predict(...), it just returns zeros or ones. Could you please tell me where I am going wrong and how I can get probabilitie of belonging to a class?

```
input_stock = Input(shape=input_shape,dtype='float32')  
stock_data= Conv2D(32, (1,5), padding='same', activation='relu')(input_stock)
stock_data = MaxPooling2D((1,2),strides=(1,2))(stock_data)
stock_data= Conv2D(8, (1,5), padding='same', activation='relu')(stock_data)
stock_data = MaxPooling2D((1,5),strides=(1,5))(stock_data)
stock_data= Conv2D(8, (154,5), padding='same', activation='relu')(stock_data)
stock_data = MaxPooling2D((1,2),strides=(1,2))(stock_data)

stock_data=Flatten()(stock_data)
stock_data=Dropout(.5)(stock_data)
output_layer = Dense(maxnumassets, activation='sigmoid')(stock_data)


model = Model(inputs=input_stock, outputs=output_layer)



return model
```

```
Output of model.predict (there are 150 classes), looks like below. 

array([[1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1.,
        0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.,
        0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.,
        0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1.,
        0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
        1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1.,
        0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)'''

Dimensions of the data are as follows:

train (715, 150, 100, 2)
ytrain (715, 150)
xtest (80, 150, 100, 2)
ytest (80, 150)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just use `model.predict(xtest)` directly, then your code will in general give values other than 0 and 1, cf. the example below which does nothing but apply your model to random data.

If yours doesn't, perhaps you're overfitting, or your model simply fits your data perfectly. Try applying `model.predict` to an array that has nothing to do with your data.

One other thing that seems off is that you've giving in your example output an array of shape `(1, 150)`, but if `xtest.shape` is indeed `(80, 150, 100, 2)`, then `model.predict(xtest).shape` is `(80, 150)`.

```py
input_shape = (150, 100, 2)
maxnumassets = 150
input_stock = Input(shape=input_shape,dtype='float32')
stock_data = Conv2D(32, (1,5), padding='same', activation='relu')(input_stock)
stock_data = MaxPooling2D((1,2),strides=(1,2))(stock_data)
stock_data = Conv2D(8, (1,5), padding='same', activation='relu')(stock_data)
stock_data = MaxPooling2D((1,5),strides=(1,5))(stock_data)
stock_data = Conv2D(8, (154,5), padding='same', activation='relu')(stock_data)
stock_data = MaxPooling2D((1,2),strides=(1,2))(stock_data)
stock_data = Flatten()(stock_data)
stock_data = Dropout(.5)(stock_data)
output_layer = Dense(maxnumassets, activation='sigmoid')(stock_data)

model = Model(inputs=input_stock, outputs=output_layer)
train = np.random.uniform(size=(775, 150, 100, 2))
ytrain = np.random.uniform(size=(775, 150))
xtest = np.random.uniform(size=(80, 150, 100, 2))
ytest = np.random.uniform(size=(80, 150))

model.compile('adam', 'mse')
model.fit(train, ytrain)
model.predict(xtest)
```

Output:

```
array([[0.50180054, 0.49852884, 0.49954456, ..., 0.4990623 , 0.49985167,
        0.4994816 ],
       [0.50180054, 0.49852884, 0.49954456, ..., 0.4990623 , 0.49985167,
        0.4994816 ],
       [0.50180054, 0.49852884, 0.49954456, ..., 0.4990623 , 0.49985167,
        0.4994816 ],
       ...,
       [0.50180054, 0.49852884, 0.49954456, ..., 0.4990623 , 0.49985167,
        0.4994816 ],
       [0.50180054, 0.49852884, 0.49954456, ..., 0.4990623 , 0.49985167,
        0.4994816 ],
       [0.50180054, 0.49852884, 0.49954456, ..., 0.4990623 , 0.49985167,
        0.4994816 ]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: I am actually just passing one sample of X_test like so: model.predict(fulltensor[109:110,:,:,:])

Comment: Also, why does your model use mse as a loss function? I am using binary_crossentropy loss, which I thought was appropriate for sigmoid. Am I wrong?

Comment: This is a multi-label problem, forgot to add.

Comment: The same behavior would occur with any objective function; modify the example above to use `'binary_crossentropy'` instead, and that works as well. When you say that this is a multi-label problem, are you in fact trying to predict a label? If so, and you want to get something out that could be interpreted as probabilities, you may want to use something like softmax instead (which shows up naturally through maximum likelihood in Poisson regression).

Comment: I am trying to predict probabilities for labels, I am not interested in one label, but probabilities of different label, given one sample in X. I see what you mean though, something is not going wrong with my data I guess, since the code should give probabilities. Will try to clean the data more and report back.

Comment: Cleaning data did not help. Here is how my original Y data looks. It is only 0s or 1s, no intermediate values. But I still would think that predict has to be produce probabilities: Y_train[:,0] array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        etc. etc.

Comment: Indeed it would; replace `ytrain` with `ytrain = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(775, 150))` in the example above, and you'll still get numbers strictly between 0 and 1. If your result doesn't happen to also match `ytest`, you're probably just overfitting?

Comment: There is something other than overfitting going on. It does not match and it does that even if I stop learning after one epoch.

Comment: Alright, I was able to replicate it by multiplying X  by 50 or more. What is weird is that it is not a consistent threshold, jumps from time to time. Apparently, Keras (or just the optimization setup) cannot handle large numbers and I do have large numbers (in the 100s of thousands) in my second channel. Probably optimization gets really confused by it and gets stuck on hill somewhere. Is there any guideline on magnitudes various models can handle? Seems like a very important topic. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The inconsistency is not necessarily weird: With nothing else specified, all parameters are initialized to small (compared to your inputs) random values; this can be configured though.